# Test action not being invoked by other users on Google Home device

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

We have developed a prototype for Google Home and running user tests but have found that the 'test' Action is only triggered on my voice and NOT available to others trying to invoke (device is registered to my development account).

Is there some some restriction?

Answer (score 2):

Testing an Action makes it available for the account which activated the test. It does *not* make it available for *every* account on a device - Actions do not load anything on the device itself, they simply permit the account to the trigger commands on Google's server.

If you want other users on the device to access the Action, you need to explicitly permit them to the action. You can [see the details](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/simulator#share_access_to_your_project), or they're listed if you click the share icon in the simulator, but in short:

1. Click the gear in the upper left of the console and then the *Permissions* menu item.
2. Add team members to the project using the *Add* button on the top. I usually give them Editor or Viewer project roles.
3. They then need to visit the simulator page to activate it. They can use the simulator to test, but it is also available on their devices.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the account from which you are testing your actions should be given to other testers to test your actions. The account should be connected to the user's Google home to test your actions.